# Objective value estimate for branches I create in Cplex

Tags: cplex, branch-and-bound, cplex-python-api

I' implementing custom branching heuristics for Cplex in python.  I have a way to choose a (binary) variable to branch on, so use the following code to create two branches from BranchCallback (following one of the Cplex examples):

```
self.make_branch(self.get_objective_value(), [(var_to_branch, "U", 0)])
self.make_branch(self.get_objective_value(), [(var_to_branch, "L", 1)])
```

I'd like to understand if I should be more clever with the objective value estimate as I noticed that Cplex explores the tree by first trying the branches with all variables assigned value 0, which works worse than the default behaviour of Cplex. In case I need to provide better estimates, are there efficient ways of getting them other than solving relaxations myself?

Answer (score 2):

Since

> branching rules are crucial for the performance of solvers they are
> also a very well-guarded secret. I can say from experience that some
> form of reliability branching is sufficient to get a reasonable solver
> performance (not top of the class though).

Also, there are some resources that might be helpful.

- [Branching rules in commercial MIP solvers](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/52/branching-rules-in-commercial-mip-solvers)
- [Measuring the impact of branching rules for mixed-integer programming by Gerald Gamrath](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320625081_Measuring_the_impact_of_branching_rules_for_mixed-integer_programming)
- [Branching rules revisited by Tobias Achterberg](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/%7Echvatal/workshop06/akm.pdf)